# shell script: how to read the whole section content in a property file

Tags: shell, awk

Currently, i have a property file like this:

```
[default]
aa=aa
bb=bb

[dev]
aa=aa
dd=dd
```

If I want to get a certain value in a section, I can use following code:

```
awk -F '=' '/\['$section'\]/{a=1}a==1&&$1~/'$key'/{print $2;exit}' $configfile
```

But How can I get the whole section, e.g. I want a list to hold all values in **dev** section?

Can any one help with this?

[edit]

I may want the all values in a section to be saved in a list like this:

```
list=()
list=`get_section dev`
```

and the list content can be:

```
aa bb
```

Thanks again for your kindly help!

Comment: could you add sample values for `$section` and `$key` and post complete expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following would be my solution to extract a section:

```
awk '/^\[/{x=0} $1=="["section"]"{x=1} x' section="$section" my.ini
```

This avoids any issues with blank lines within a section. It doesn't, however, print the list of results, or turn them into shell variables, which I gather is what you're looking for.

If your shell is bash, you might take advantage of arrays, and avoid the need for awk altogether.  Associative arrays are a feature of bash 4:

```
declare -A conf

while IFS='=' read var val; do
    if [[ $var == \[*] ]]; then
        section="${var//[^[:alnum:]]/}"    # strip invalid chars from variable name
    elif [[ -n "$val" ]]; then
        echo " > ${section}_$var=$val"     # debugging
        declare "${section}_$var=$val"     # set to vars, bash 3
        conf["${section}_$var"]="$val"     # store in associative array, bash 4
    fi
done < my.ini
```

This stores your *entire* configuration in variables or a bash array. If you want to trim leading spaces from your values, the easiest way would be to set `IFS='= '` instead of just `'='`.

The equivalent in POSIX shell might look something like:

```
while IFS='=' read var val; do
    if expr "$var" : '[[].*[]]$' >/dev/null; then
        section="$(echo "$var" | tr -d '][')"
    elif [ -n "$val" ]; then
        echo " > ${section}_$var=$val"          # debugging
        eval "${section}_$var=\"$val\""         # set to vars, POSIX
    fi
done < my.ini
```

The result of this would be a set of variables similar to what the `declare` bash 3 option above would provide. But with POSIX, we'd be stuck with `eval`.

If you want a random-access method to extract a variable from a section in bash, you could do it as a function:

```
function confitem() {

    # Usage: confitem section itemname

    local -A conf
    local var val section
    local retval=1

    while IFS='=' read var val; do
        if [[ $var == \[*] ]]; then
            section="$var"
        elif [[ -n $val ]] && [[ $section == $1 ]] && [[ $var == $2 ]]; then
            printf '%s' "$val"     # print the result
            retval=0               # set a return value for the function
            break                  # and quit the loop.
        fi
    done < my.ini
    return $retval

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
section="dev"
awk -F'=' -v s="$section" '/^\[/{ gsub(/[\[\]]/, "", $1); f = ($1 == s); next }
                           NF && f{ print $2 }' file
```

The output:

```
aa
dd
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is consistent with no blank lines in any section and if the blank lines between sections does not contain any whitespace, you can clear the record separator do something like:

```
awk '$1 == "["section"]"' section="$section" RS= "$configfile"
```

or

```
awk '$2 == s' s="$section" FS=[][] RS= "$configfile"
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "a list to hold all values", but if you just want to print the values, you can easily post-process with `cut -d= -f2`

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
section=dev
sed '/'"$section"'/,/^$/!d;/=/!d;s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/' "$configfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and came up with a solution similar to others here.
The main difference is it uses a single `awk` call to get a response suitable for creating an associative array of the property/value pairs for a section.

Here's a testing script demonstrating the `awk` and `declare` statements used;

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Parse a INI style properties file and extract property values for a given section
# 
# Author: Alan Carlyle
# License: CC0 (https://creativecommons.org/about/cclicenses/)
#
# Example Input: (example.properties)
#  [SEC1]
#  item1=value1
#  item2="value 2"
#
#  [Section 2]
#  property 1="Value 1 of 'Section 2'"
#  property 2='Single "quoted" value'
#
# Usage:  
# $ read_props example.properties "Section 2" property\ 2
# $ Single "quoted" value
#
# Section names and properties with spaces do not need to be quoted. 
# Values with spaces must be quoted. Values can use single or double quotes.
# The following characters [ = ] can not be used in names or values.
#
# If the property is not provided the the whole section is outputed.
#

propertiesFile=$1
section=$2
property=$3

# Extract the propetites for the section formated as for associtive array
sectionData="( "$(awk -F'=' -v s="$section" '/^\[/{ gsub(/[\[\]]/, "", $1); f = ($1 == s); next } 
    NF && f{ print "["$1"]="$2 }' $propertiesFile)" )"

# Create associtive array from extracted section data
declare +x -A "properties=$sectionData"

if [ -z "$property" ] 
then
  echo $sectionData
else
  echo ${properties[$property]}
fi
```