# Read value of multiple instances of a variable from .conf file - bash script

Tags: bash, shell, config

I am trying print the value of a variable which is repeating over more than one section in a .conf file.
Example of .conf file as below

```
[FILTER1]
LogLevel=DLT_LOG_INFO
File=offline_log1
FileSize=20000000
NOFiles=2
EcuID=ECU1
SyncBehavior=ON_SPECIFIC_SIZE
SpecificSize=4096

[FILTER2]
LogLevel=DLT_LOG_INFO
File=offline_log2
FileSize=20000000
NOFiles=1
EcuID=ECU1
SyncBehavior=ON_SPECIFIC_SIZE
SpecificSize=4096
```

Need to read this .conf file in another bash script and echo the value of *NoFiles* variable line by line

so far I tried,
with the following script I am able get only the last occurrence of the variable

```
#! /bin/bash
. dlt_logstorage.conf
echo "$NOFiles"
```

Comment: If you want to print only the values: `sed -n 's/^NOFiles=//p' file.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The **section names** have no effects on shell variables assignment, so the second one will replace the first one.

The file format you proposed is the **Windows INI file** format. At [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149333/shell-script-how-to-read-the-whole-section-content-in-a-property-file) you can find some solutions to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to print the values, this shall do your job.

```
field="NOFiles"
sed -n "s/$field=\(.*\)/\1/p" file.conf
```